# php - Foreach - Wrapping <li> </li> with two results inside, then repeating.

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, counter, html-lists

Working with php - 
Im trying to run a "foreach" on an array, but i want to wrap every two results in li tags. Output will look like this.

`<li>`

`<div>result 1</div>`

`<div>result 2</div>`

`</li>`

`<li>`

`<div>result 3</div>`

`<div>result 4</div>`

`</li>`

`<li>`

`<div>result 5</div>`

`<div>result 6</div>`

`</li>`

how do i go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 2);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // $chunk could have either 2 elements, or just one on the last iteration on an array with odd number of elements
    echo '<li>';
    foreach ($chunk as $value) {
        echo '<div>' . $value . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
echo "<li>";
foreach($results as $pos => $result) {
    if ($pos > 2 && $pos % 2 == 0) {
        echo "</li>\n<li>";
    }
    echo "<div>result $result</div>";
}
echo "</li>";
```

or more simply:

```
$results = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$max = count($results);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<div>result " . $results[$i] . "</div>";
    $i++;
    echo "<div>result " . $results[$i] . "</div>";
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: This is going to have the same problem as some of the other posts, you need to check for a valid value in case there are odd # of elements, and if it's the last (and odd) one, close the html tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    ++$count;
    if ($count == 1) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<div>" . $value."</div>";    
    } else {
        echo "<div>" . $value."</div>";    
        echo "</li>";
        $count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're missing a "$" sign on count and this will result in an unclosed li on an odd count.

Comment: actually, those were two separate issues :p